# writing a simple for loop in php for a css progress bar

Tags: php, mysql, css, loops, progress-bar

I have a projectstatus in my mysql database. Depending on the status, it's 1, 2 or 3. Also I have a css status bar of which I can set the width of, to see the progress.

Here's the example code:

```
<td>" . $projstatid ."
    <div class='meter-wrap'>
        <div class='meter-value' style='background-color: #0a0; width: 33,3%;'>
            <div class='meter-text'></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Now I can do 3 if statements at the width's size like:

`if ($projstatid) = 1 { echo "33.3%"; } elseif {..} else {...}`

But how do I write a simple loop which loops through the numbers untill it reaches the `$projstatid`'s value, but every time it re-loops adds 33.3%?

Even better would be if the loop devided the amount time of loopings by the max amount of projstatids. But that I'll figure out, once I have this basic loop working.

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to do is to create a loop which does this:

```
x=1
y=0
$projectstatid = $record['projectstatid'] (in this example lets say it's 5)

loop: x=1, is it 5? Nope. return: y= +20%
loop: x=2, is it 5? Nope. return: y= +20%
etc.
```

untill it reaches 5 (and it will return 100%)

Comment: why are you doing a mysql escape on a string you're inserting into HTML? unless this is going into a query, it's a pointless/useless operation.

Comment: So what exactly do you want?

Comment: Will show us the output your are wanting? I had no idea what your question is even asking.

Comment: you are right about the escape. Ok let me re-folmulate.

Comment: The correct operator should be == and both operands need to be inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to compute the percent corresponding to your current value :

```
$percent = floor($number * 100 / $nbmax);
```

Here `$percent` is the value to put in your css and `$number` is your current status and `$nbmax` is the maximum value that it could have.

In your case your would have :

```
$number  = $record['projstatid'];
$nbmax = 3;
$percent = floor($number * 100 / $nbmax);
```

**EDIT**: Based on your edit I guess you want something like this:

```
$number = 5;
for($i = 1 ; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $percent = floor($i * 100 / $number);
    echo $percent;
}
```

Comment: As the others I have no idea what you mean for the loop. Do you mean for each value retrieved from mysql ?

Comment: @koopajah: I don't think he wants the echo inside of the loop, just a single echo that corresponds to `$number`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of incrementing `$x` until `$x == $projectstatid`, you could use a `switch` (which is sort of a loop):

```
switch ($projectstatid)
{
    case 1:
        $y = '20%';
    break;
    case 2:
        $y = '40%';
    break;
    //etc, until the max is reached, in which case:
    default:
        $y = '100%';
}
```

See [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for all info concerning the `switch` statement.
Also if this: `if ($projstatid) = 1 { echo "33.3%"; } elseif {..} else {...}` is what your code looks like, it's no surprise that it keeps echo-ing `33%`, because `=` is the assignment operator, and assigning to a variable will almost always return true. Also, your parentheses are not where they should be, what it should look like is this:

```
if ($projstatid == 1)
{
    echo "33.3%";
}
else if ($projstatid == 2)
{..}
else {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $meter_val = 0; ?>
<?php if ($projstatid <= 5) $meter_val = ($projstatid * 20);
<td>" . $projstatid ."
 <div class='meter-wrap'>
  <div class='meter-value' style='background-color: #0a0; width: <?php echo $meter_val; ?>%;'>
    <div class='meter-text'></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</td>
```